# How to prove Gauss-Bonnet theorem

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry

Our professor is asking us to study Gauss-Bonnet theorem, but personally, I haven't taken neither topology nor differential geometry, how am I supposed to start approaching this theorem? I have read many articles online about how other people prove this theorem, but honestly I have no clue what they are trying to write.

To ensure we are talking about the same theorem, the link is the following: [Gauss-Bonnet Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss%E2%80%93Bonnet_theorem)

The course I am taking is classical geometry, and this topic is just an extension of topics that we are covering in lecture, and it's like every student is randomly assigned a topics to study, and it just happen to me that I was assigned to this topics.

Really need some help here, sincerely appreciated.

Comment: Why don't you ask your professor? They should be able to suggest a reference that is in line with the the material in your course better than strangers on the internet can.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See chapter 4 of Do Carmo's "Differential geometry of curves and surfaces". The text is almost self contained.